# Are there any Security Concerns to using Python F Strings with User Input

Tags: exploit, python, format-string

## Background

A while ago I started using F strings in Python but remembered seeing some security concerns with using them with user input so I have made a point of not using them for those situations.

## Question

Are there security concerns to using python f strings with user input. For example, is it possible for a user to gain access to information that they shouldn't have access to.

## Example

```
$ ./hello.py mike
hi mike
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

secrete = 'my secrete'

print(F"hi {sys.argv[1]}")
```

This program is basically a basic hello world that takes user input.  Is it possible for an attacker to supply an input that would exfiltrate the secrete variable or any other valuable data?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you do with it. Your new string contains user input so if, for example, you pass it off to `os.system` you now have RCE.

Comment: ok, so I'm aware of that, but that would be the same with any user input method.  Since the F string is computed at runtime, I'm wondering if you can force it to eval a statement like if I passed in `1+1`. I did try that and it just interprets it as a string so no problem there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Python's f-strings are actually safer.** Use them!

---

String formatting may be dangerous when a format string depends on untrusted data. So, when using  `str.format()` or `%`-formatting, it's important to use static format strings, or to sanitize untrusted parts before applying the formatter function. In contrast, *f-strings* aren't actually plain strings, but more like syntactic sugar for concatenating strings and expressions. As such, an f-string's format is predetermined and doesn't allow dynamic (potentially untrusted) parts in the first place.

### Old-style formatting with `str.format()`

```
>>> data_str = 'bob'
>>> format_str = 'hello {name}!'
>>> format_str.format(name=data_str)
'hello bob!'
```

Here, your Python interpreter doesn't know the difference between a data string and a format string. It just calls a function, `str.format()`, which runs a replacement algorithm on the format string value at the moment of execution. So, expectedly, the format is just a plain string with curly braces in it:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("'hello {name}!'")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('hello {name}!')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

### New-style formatting with f-strings

```
>>> data_str = 'bob'
>>> f'hello {data_str}!'
'hello bob!'
```

Here, `f'hello {data_str}!'` may look like a string constant, but it's not. The interpreter doesn't parse the part between `{...}` as part of the string that may be expanded later, but as a separate expression:

```
>>> dis.dis("f'hello {name}!'")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('hello ')
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (name)
              4 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('!')
              8 BUILD_STRING             3
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, think of `"hi {sys.argv[1]}"` as (approximately) syntactical sugar for `"hi " + sys.argv[1]`. At run time, the interpreter doesn't even really know or care that you used an f-string. It just sees instructions to build a string from a the constant `"hi "` and the formatted value of `sys.argv[1]`.

### Vulnerable example

Here is a sample web app which uses `str.format()` in a vulnerable way:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

secret = 'abc123'

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    name = 'funtimes'
    msg = 'welcome to {site.name}'
    def do_GET(self):
        res = ('<title>' + self.path + '</title>\n' + self.msg).format(site=self)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(res.encode())

HTTPServer(('localhost', 8888), Handler).serve_forever()
```

```
$ python3 example.py

$ curl 'http://localhost:8888/test'
<title>/test</title>
welcome to funtimes
```

#### Attack

When the `res` string is built, it uses`self.path` as part of the format string. Since `self.path` is user-controlled, we can use it to alter the format string and e.g. exfiltrate the global variable `secret`:

```
$ curl -g 'http://localhost:8888/XXX{site.do_GET.__globals__[secret]}'
<title>/XXXabc123</title>
welcome to funtimes
```

Answer (score 4):

If this basic language feature were this flawed, it probably wouldn't be a feature at all. As long as the contents of the format string are controlled by the programmer at development time, there is nothing that a user can do to abuse them.

The contents of the curly braces are evaluated, but the result of that evaluation is not evaluated again (i.e. `sys.argv[1]` is evaluated to "1+1", but is not evaluated again, like you have seen).

The problem arises when a user is able to to inject data into a string *before* it is formatted; see [this challenge example](https://github.com/lovasoa/pyformat-challenge). While this is not for an f-string, it is a good demonstration of the attacks that are possible if the user is allowed to control the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The security concern about the f-string is that you don't want to use it as a template directly.

The ability to execute code in the f-string is much more powerful than calling `.format()` of a string template.

For example, below is what the f-string can do but call `.format()` can not:

```
>>> d = {'name': 'Jarvis', 'age': 1}
>>> f'{d["name"]}'  # access a dict via keys
'Jarvis'
>>> f'{d.keys()}'  # call functions
"dict_keys(['name', 'age'])"
>>> f'{(lambda x: x + 1)(d["age"])}'  # write a lambda
'2'
```

Python locks the ability of f-string by ensuring any f-string in the code cannot be delay evaluated. So actually, you cannot use an f-string as a dynamic template like from the user's input. For example, you cannot read a string from an HTTP request's query string and use it as an f-string.

The only exception is to explicitly use `eval()` on a string to make it an f-string. Like

```
f_string_tmpl = 'My name is {name}.'
eval(f'f\'{f_string_tmpl}\'', {}, {'name': 'Wang'})
```

Or we can say that the f-string is pretty safe, since unless we `eval()` we shall keep everything under control.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following simple example:

```
import sys

secret = "My secret"

print(f"From argv: {sys.argv[1]}\n")
print(f"From code: {print(secret)}")
```

If you run it with `python test.py print\(secret\)` or `python test.py "print(secret)"` the result is:

```
From argv: print(secret)

My secret
From code: None
```

The argument is simply treated as a string, it is not executed.
However, I am *not* 100 % sure there is no way to force Python to somehow execute it.
I am also not sure what would happen if the data came from some another input, like socket for instance.

Comment: @MikeSchem you have destroyed the example. Why have you removed the print from the `print(f"From code: {secret}")`. It has been crucial to show what is going on. Revert the changes because now it makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, I was unsure what you were trying to demonstrate.  I see now.

Comment: Doesn't this sample prove that it does execute the `print()`?

Comment: It executes the print, but not the one provided by the user as an argument.

Comment: Are you sure?  It looks like line 3 in your output is printing out the secrete.

Comment: Oh, I see, never mind.