# Is format string still an issue in Python?

Tags: python, format-string

I am not familiar with Python. I found lots of places talking about the format string issue in python. To understand its impact, I created a very simple test code:

```
# assume this CONFIG holds sensitive information
CONFIG = {
    "KEY": "abcdefg"
}
  
class PeopleInfo:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
  
# case 1: st obtained from user
jobId = input()
print("Job ID: {}".format(jobId))
```

Assume this is vulnerable code, if I provide an expression through the input, it supposes to trigger that expression. However, it just returns the expression I put in the input as String. For example if I input: `{people_obj.__init__.__globals__[CONFIG][KEY]}`, it will just returns Job ID: `{people_obj.__init__.__globals__[CONFIG][KEY]}`.

Does it mean the issue has been solved in newer Python version? Should developer still take care of it?

Comment: format string vulnerability is about using a format string (in your case `Job ID: {}`) which includes untrusted user input. Your example does not do this, i.e. your format string is a static string hard coded in the program. This is explained in more detail in [Are there any Security Concerns to using Python F Strings with User Input](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238338/are-there-any-security-concerns-to-using-python-f-strings-with-user-input)

Comment: thanks a lot for quick answer! So, if the untrusted input is provided as an argument to a string formatting function, it is actually not vulnerable to format string attack. Is my understanding right?

Comment: By the very definition of a [format string attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Format_string_attack) the attacker needs to control (part of) the format string. This is not true in your example, so it cannot be vulnerable to a format string attack. It can of course still be vulnerable to other attack types, although I don't see any in your short example.